# Module Augmentation with Generics

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

In typescript, is it possible to update generic arguments to a type when augmenting a module in some consuming code.

For example, if my module looks something like

```
// my-module.ts

export type FuncProps<T extends string = "foo"> = Record<T, number>;

export function myFunc(props: FuncProps) {
  // do something...
}
```

(I export both the function and the type from the library...)

Then, somewhere in code that consumes this module I have something like...

```
// types.d.ts

import { FuncProps } from 'my-module';

declare module "my-module" {
  type FuncProps<"bar">
}
```

in another place in the consuming project

```
import { myFunc } from 'my-module';

myFunc({ bar: 100 })
```

Now the function takes *bar* and not *foo* because of our declaration in the consuming project.

Is this possible? And if so, what would I need to change about my code example given here to make it work?

Comment: Personally it sounds a bit hacky to me to modify the types of another module in this way. What about defining a type alias and exporting that? E.g. `export type BarFuncProps = FuncProps<"bar">`

Comment: No doubt a bit hacky. With your solution though, it isn't clear how I would let the compiler/intellisense know that `myFunc` takes `BarFuncProps` in the consuming code.

Comment: I was thinking that the consuming code would simply import the `BarFuncProps` type and use it in `myFunc` to declare what arguments it expects.